# Web page performance testing on web page which use javascript to load content

Tags: html, performance, testing, gatling

I want to do performance tests for the web page.
I use the Gatling, but I've got this message:
*"This page uses JavaScript and requires a JavaScript enabled browser. Your browser is not JavaScript enabled."*
I've read Gatling documentation and I've found that Galting won't run javascript.
There is the possibility to test this web page using Gatling?
If not, how can I perform performance tests for this page? Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 1):

This HTML page always contains this message. And then, JavaScript hides it. This is a trick to display something to the user agent when it doesn't support JavaScript.

Then, you have to understand how load test tools work. They are kind of rich HTTP clients, not web browsers, and indeed, they don't execute JavaScript. It means you have to figure out which HTTP requests the JavaScript executing in your browser sends to the server and include them in your test. Gatling's [Recorder](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/recorder/) can help you discover those requests.